# C++ Initializing my own IOStreans

Tags: c++, iostream

**Objective:**
Lets suppose that I'm writing a C++ console application that needs to read & write text to 3 distinct console windows.

**Question:**
How can I initialize the following IOStream objects

```
ostream& out_1, out_2, out_3;
istream& in_1, in_2, in_3;
```

such that they each stream to/from console windows titled *"Window #1"*, *"Window #2"*, & *"Window #3"* respectively?
If I need to derive a new `streambuf`, please explain/demonstrate what would be involved in this process.

**Clarification:**

- This question is more to satisfy my curiosity concerning IOStream
  utilities than to satisfy a requirement for an actual application.
- Aside from printing to different windows, I want each of the final stream objects to function identically to `cout` or `cin` respectively.

**On a Side Note:**
This is not to constitute an answer, but rather something that would make a helpful comment:
Does anyone know of any good reference material concerning C++ IOStreams? The only useful material I've been able to find is the book *Standard C++ IOStreams and Locales*, by Angelika Langer and Klaus Kreft.

**Update:**

1. I have received feedback from @DanielJour in the comments saying that it is a platform specific process. If there is no other work-around using only IOStreams, I would like answers to use the Windows API.
2. In case this isn't already clear, none of the necessary console windows have been initialized anywhere else in the code. Part of my question is intended to cover what method IOStreams uses to initialize console windows, and whether this method could be used more than once in a given program.

Comment: This is platform specific. On Linux, you just have to open the corresponding nodes in the filesystem.

Comment: Where do these "console windows" come from? Are you using windows or linux? Do these windows actually allow/enable you to read from/write to them?

Comment: With respect to the question in the Side Note: Nicolai Josuttis's "The C++ Standard Library" contains, at least, basics of creating stream buffers. I think it is sufficient to get started. I'm biased, however: I wrote the initial version of the corresponding sections...